# Error installing PHP PEAR ubuntu 12.04

Tags: php, ubuntu

I have installed PHP PEAR in ubuntu using

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear
```

After successfull installation first time.When I try to run it in **terminal**, it shows error:

```
The program 'pear' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install php-pear
```

I again tried to install it. Then it shows that

```
php-pear is already the newest version.
```

I have checked many questions on SO. In every question it is mentioned to locate pear etc. But above mentioned error is not solved.

I even tried installing pear many times with sudo and running it. It gives same error.

Please help to sort it out.

Comment: How are you running he pear command?

Comment: What do you mean "When I try to run it"?  Are you including PEAR code in your PHP page? Are you running something from the command line?

Comment: If I run command pear in terminal it says pear is not installed.

Comment: You running pear with /usr/bin/pear? Try `wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar` and
`php go-pear.phar`

Comment: @bedna It is solved as you said. Thanks. But why it is not working with apt-get install?

Comment: You probably have PHP >= 5.3 and the package only works with PHP <= 5.2. I think :)

Comment: @bedna - please right your comment as an answer as it solved the OP's question.

Comment: @bedna yes you can as mamdouh told

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Package php-pear in Ubuntu 12.04 only works with PHP <= 5.2

For PHP >= 5.3 use

```
wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
php go-pear.phar
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove PEAR and PHP, then start from the beginning. I hope this solves your problem.